Sent image does not appear in React and laravel
I am developing a chat application with Laravel and React. I want to send pictures in the chat, but the sent pictures do not appear or are distorted. I've been dealing with this problem for a long time.
First of all, I send information about the file to the data column in my database.and I brodcasting my event.
public function uploadFile(Request $request, $to)
    {
        $from = $request->input('from');
        $file = $request->file('file');

        $from = User::find($from);
        $to = User::find($to);

        if ($from && $to && $file) {
            $filePath = $file->store('message-files');
            $fileName = basename($filePath);

            $log = new MessageLog;
            $log->channel = 'agent-' . $from->id . '-' . $to->id;
            $log->from = $from->id;
            $log->to = $to->id;
            $log->save();
            $log->setData([
                'file_path' => $filePath,
                'file_name' => $fileName,
                'file_orginal_name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                'file_size' => $file->getSize(),
            ]);
            $log->load('from');
            $log->load('to');

            broadcast(new AgentFileEvent($from, $to, $file));
            return response(['result' => $log]);
        }
        if (!$file) {
            return response(['message' => 'no file uploaded'], 400);
        }

    }



public function fileDownload(Request $request, $name)
    {
        if (Storage::fileExists('message-files/' . $name)) {
            return Storage::download('message-files/' . $name);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'File ' . $name . ' not found!',
        ]);
    }

Burada formdata'ya gönderdiğim görselleri axios request ile çağırıyorum. Ve addMessage'a ile resulta gönderiyorum.
const sendFile = (file) => {
        let url, formData;


        formData=new FormData();
        formData.append('to',active.to.id)
        formData.append('from',active.from.id)
        formData.append('file',file)

        if (formData) {
            axios.post(Route.get('upload-file', {
                    'to': active.to.id,
                }), formData)
                .then(result => {
                    if (result.data.result !== undefined) {
                        addMessage(result.data.result);
                    }

                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log("ERROR:", error);
                });
        }

    }

The purpose of using addMessage was actually to receive messages, but I also used it to receive images. Could the problem originate from here?
Messages and images received via the OpenChat method need to be listed.
const openChat = (active) => {
        setActive(active);
        Storage.set('active', active);
        markMessageAsRead( active.to.id, active.from.id );
        loadMessages();
        console.log('channel:', 'agent-'+active.to.id+'-'+active.from.id);
        console.log('listen:', '.agent-'+active.from.id+'-'+active.to.id);
        window.Echo.private('agent-'+active.to.id+'-'+active.from.id).listen('.agent-'+active.from.id+'-'+active.to.id, (e) => {
            addMessage(e);
            console.log(e);
            loadMessages();
        });
        window.Echo.join(active.channel);
    }


I used these two methods for sending messages.
const loadMessages = () =>
    {
        if(!isObjectEmpty(active)){
            let url, data;

            if(active.type == 'private'){
                url = Route.get('chat-get-agent')
                data = {
                    from: active.from.id,
                    to: active.to.id
                };
            }

            if(active.type == 'channel'){
                url = Route.get('chat-get-channel', {'channel': active.data.name})
                data = {};
            }

            if(url !== undefined && data !== undefined){
                axios.post(url, data)
                .then(response => {
                    if(response.data.result !== undefined) setMessages(response.data.result.reverse())
                })
                .catch(error => { console.log("ERROR:: ", error.response.data); });
            }
        }


    }

    const sendMessage = (message) => {
        if(!isObjectEmpty(active)){
            let url, data;

            if(active.type == 'private'){
                url = Route.get('chat-agent-event', {'to': active.to.id})
                data = {
                    from: active.from.id,
                    to: active.to.id,
                    message: message,
                    from_details: active.from,
                    to_details: active.to
                };
            }

            if(active.type == 'channel'){
                url = Route.get('chat-channel-event', {'channel': active.data.name})
                data = {
                    from: active.from.id,
                    message: message,
                    from_details: active.from,
                    channel: active.data
                };
            }

            if(url !== undefined && data !== undefined){
                axios.post(url, data)
                    .then(result => {
                        if(result.data.result !== undefined) addMessage(result.data.result);
                    })
                    .catch(error => { console.log("ERROR:: ", error); });
            }





            axios.post(Route.get('send-notification'), { 'to':active.to.id, 'data': data });
        }


    }

I created this component to send messages and images.
class MessageSender extends React.Component {
    static contextType = ChatContext
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            message: "",
            result: "",
            active: {},
            file: "",
            type: "message",

        };

        this.setMessage = this.setMessage.bind(this);
        this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
        this._handleKeyDown = this._handleKeyDown.bind(this);
        this.handleFileChange = this.handleFileChange.bind(this);
        this.sendFile = this.sendFile.bind(this);

        this.fileInputRef = React.createRef();
    }


    setMessage(event) {
        this.setState({
            message: event.target.value
        })
    }


    sendMessage() {
        if (this.state.type == 'message') {
            this.context.sendMessage(this.state.message)
            this.setState({ message: "" });
            globalScrollRef.scrollTo(0, globalScrollRef.scrollHeight);
        }

        if (this.state.type == 'file') {
            this.context.sendFile(this.state.file)
            this.setState({ file: '' });
            globalScrollRef.scrollTo(0, globalScrollRef.scrollHeight);
        }

    }


    handleFileChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            file: event.target.files[0],
            type: "file",
        });

    }

    handleDefaultState() {
        this.setState({
            type: "message",
        });
    }

    _handleKeyDown(event) {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.sendMessage()
        }
    }
    sendFile() {
        this.context.sendFile(this.state.file)
        this.setState({ file: "" });
        globalScrollRef.scrollTo(0, globalScrollRef.scrollHeight);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="nk-chat-editor">
                <div className="nk-chat-editor-upload  ms-n1">
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-trigger text-primary toggle-opt" data-target="chat-upload"><em className="icon ni ni-plus-circle-fill" onClick={() => { this.handleDefaultState() }}></em></a>
                    <div className="chat-upload-option" data-content="chat-upload">
                        <ul className="">

                            <li>
                                <label htmlFor="fileInput">
                                    <em className="icon ni ni-img-fill"></em>
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="file"
                                    id="fileInput"
                                    name='file'
                                    onChange={this.handleFileChange}
                                />
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><em className="icon ni ni-camera-fill"></em></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><em className="icon ni ni-mic"></em></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><em className="icon ni ni-grid-sq"></em></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="nk-chat-editor-form">
                    <div className="form-control-wrap">
                        <textarea className="form-control form-control-simple no-resize" rows="1" id="default-textarea" placeholder="Type your message..." onChange={this.setMessage} onKeyDown={this._handleKeyDown} value={this.state.message}></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul className="nk-chat-editor-tools g-2">
                    <li>
                        <button className="btn btn-round btn-primary btn-icon" onClick={() => { this.sendMessage() }}><em className="icon ni ni-send-alt"></em></button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

This section is the component I use to list incoming messages and images.
class Message extends React.Component {
    static contextType = ChatContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            message: (this.props.message !== undefined ? this.props.message : ""),
            is_me: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { session } = this.context;
        const { message } = this.state;

        let date = "";
        let is_me = false;
        if (message.from.id === session.id) {
            is_me = true;
        }
        if (message.created_at) {
            date = moment(message.created_at).fromNow();
        }

        if (message.data !== null && message.data !== undefined) {
            try {
                var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
                var downloadUrl = Route.get('download-file', { 'name': data.file_name });
                message.message = <img src={downloadUrl} style={{ maxSize: "100px" }} />
            } catch (error) {
                //console.error("Error parsing message data:", error);
                message.message = ""
            }
        }
        return (
            <div className={`chat ${is_me ? 'is-me' : 'is-you'}`}>
                {is_me ? null : (
                    <div className="chat-avatar">
                        <div className="user-avatar bg-purple">
                            <span>{message.from.name.charAt(0)}{message.from.surname.charAt(0)}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
                <div className="chat-content">
                    <div className="chat-bubbles">
                        <div className="chat-bubble">
                            <div className="chat-msg">{message.message}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul className="chat-meta">
                        <li>{message.from.name}</li>
                        <li>{date}</li>
                        {is_me && message.is_read && <li><i className="far fa-check-circle" style={{ color: 'green' }}></i></li>}

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

enter image description here
enter image description here
The image looks like this. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

What does the "download-file" route do?

To download incoming files . Are you saying the download-files are wrong?
